# read and write zip lists in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking to read and write python zip lists - but I am not able to find excatly how to acheive ethis. So, I have the following:

```
zipofalllists=zip([a],[b],[c],[d],[e]..)
```

where [a],[b],[c],[d],[e] are just lists (mix made of strings, integers and floats) of equal dimension.

Now, id like to write and read this zip list to/from a text file. I was thinking of writing the zipofalllists as a csv at first - but I am not sure this is the right approach.

So, I have something like:

```
with open("master_csv_file.csv", "wb") as f:
    fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter='|',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in zip(*masterzip):
        fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

but.. I am not sure this is the right approach. This way I do get a csv file, but I am unsure also on how to read and unpack this csv back to the original lists (newbie here - please excuse this 101 question).

Confused as to what is the best/fool proof approach here.

Comment: What do you mean by a "zip list"? zip simply returns a list like any other.

Comment: If you don't need it to be read externally, the `pickle`/`cPickle` module is one option

Comment: Is your question how to undo the `zip` operation? You can use `zip(*zipofalllists)` -> `[(a,), (b,), (c,), (d,), (e,), ..]`

Answer (score 1):

James,

So what you're doing is completely independent from zipping the lists together.  Basically, after you zip the lists, you have a new list that consists of more lists.

After that, you want to save it to a file.  Since you have successfully zipped the lists, I assume writing the data structure to a file is what you want.

The easiest way to do this is to 'pickle' the data structure into a file so you can pull it back at a later date - see this link: [enter link description here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) for more info.

Good luck - if it's something else you want to do, let me/us know.

Answer (score 1):

`json` is nice, or `pickle`.

```
import json

zipofalllists=zip([a],[b],[c],[d],[e])

# write
with open("out.json", "w") as out_f:
    json.dump(zipofalllists, out_f)

# read
with open("out.json", "r") as in_f:
    alllists = json.load(in_f)
```

Both `pickle` and `json` use `load([file object])` for *read* and `dump([object], [file object])` for *writes* directly from/to a file.  You can also use `loads()` and`dumps()` to directly transfer an object to/from it's *string* representation.

Comment: thanks a lot for this - but, could you also please let me know how to read the out.json back to the correpsonding [a],[b] ,[c],[d],[e] lists?